# multi-level comments error when deleting items from database

Tags: comments

I have implemented a multi-level comment system where comments and their replies are pulled out of a SQL database and stored (via a PHP routine) in an array. Here is an example of the data structure of a comment which has 2 nested replies (main comment -> [child] reply -> [child] reply to reply):

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( **[self]** => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [page_id] => 47iNetBet [parent_id] => 0 [name] => adam 1 [email] => web@web.de [url] => [comment] => main comment [dt] => 2012-02-23 13:05:13 [ip] => 127.0.0.1 ) **[childs]** => Array ( [2] => stdClass Object ( [self] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [page_id] => 47iNetBet [parent_id] => 1 [name] => adam 2 [email] => web@web.de [url] => [comment] => 1st reply [dt] => 2012-02-23 13:05:25 [ip] => 127.0.0.1 ) **[childs]** => Array ( [3] => stdClass Object ( [self] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [page_id] => 47iNetBet [parent_id] => 2 [name] => adam 3 [email] => web@web.de [url] => [comment] => 2nd reply [dt] => 2012-02-23 13:05:35 [ip] => 127.0.0.1 ) **[childs]** => Array ( ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Each comment's parent_id refers to the id of its parent. If parent_id is zero then it's a main comment. This works fine - so far I have been able to add as many nested comments as I want without any problems. But it seems that as soon as I delete something from my database or even delete all the comments and then start adding new comments (even the exact same comments ids, parent_ids etc.) at some point the structure gets messed up. Here is the same example after deleting comments from database and repopulating database with the same comments data:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( **[self]** => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [page_id] => 47iNetBet [parent_id] => 0 [name] => adam 1 [email] => web@web.de [url] => [comment] => main comment [dt] => 2012-02-23 13:05:13 [ip] => 127.0.0.1 ) **[childs]** => Array ( [2] => stdClass Object ( [self] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [page_id] => 47iNetBet [parent_id] => 1 [name] => adam 2 [email] => web@web.de [url] => [comment] => 1st reply [dt] => 2012-02-23 13:14:40 [ip] => 127.0.0.1 ) **[childs] => Array (EMPTY???) ) ) )** [1] => stdClass Object ( [childs] => Array ( [3] => stdClass Object ( [self] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [page_id] => 47iNetBet [parent_id] => 2 [name] => adam 3 [email] => web@web.de [url] => [comment] => 2nd reply [dt] => 2012-02-23 13:14:47 [ip] => 127.0.0.1 ) [childs] => Array ( ) ) ) ) )
```

As you can see in the latter example, the second child (main comment -> reply -> reply to reply) is an empty array. What should be in this array is now put at the end as some sort of independent/incomplete comment which breaks the flow of the display. If I drop the "comments" table and start a new one everything seems to work fine again until I start deleting stuff again.

I dont know how to explain, but this is weird. I cant imagine that there is something wrong with the code as everything seems to work fine otherwise. Could this have to do anything with the database itself? Maybe someone had a similar problem? Maybe someone could point me in the right direction. I dont even know where to start looking.

Any help, suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was indeed an error within the code. The records in the database need to be fetched in a certain order (sorted by parent_id in ascending order). It was as simple as that.